# Make non numerical content from a cell show up on another table according to certain criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Apologies if this is a very basic question but I need some help.

I want content from column E to show up on line 11 depending on date on row 9 and langauge on row 10. This is basically a sumifs formula only that it doesn't work because I have non numerical content on column E.

[image]

Would like some suggestions on how to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `VLOOKUP` function

Comment: google sheets preferably, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try this in `Cell_B11`:*

```js
=filter(E4:E6, B4:B6=B9, C4:C6=B10)
```